# How to prevent moving to next page on clicking enter key using javascript in html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'am having the following code in javascript in order to navigate from textboxes and textareas. The issue is the functionality is working fine but, when clicking on enter it is navigating to next textbox, at the same time it is navigating to next page, how to prevent to navigate to next page when clicking on enter key. Can someone help me thanks.

```
 $('input[type="text"],textarea').keyup(function(e){
  if(e.which==39 || e.which==13)
   $(this).closest('td').next().find('input[type="text"],textarea').focus();
  else if(e.which==37 || e.which==8)
   $(this).closest('td').prev().find('input[type="text"],textarea').focus();
  else if(e.which==40 || e.which==13)
   $(this).closest('tr').next().find('td:eq('+$(this).closest('td').index()+')').find('input[type="text"],textarea').focus();
  else if(e.which==38 || e.which==8)
   $(this).closest('tr').prev().find('td:eq('+$(this).closest('td').index()+')').find('input[type="text"],textarea').focus();
 });
```

Comment: Better put it in a plunker and share that URL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On keyDown for your text input, catch the input if it's the enter key and prevent the default behavior:

```
$('input[type="text"],textarea').keydown(function () {
    if(event.keyCode == 13){
        event.preventDefault();
    } 
});
```

If I recall correctly, keyDown is necessary to prevent the default enter action, rather than keyUp. But give both a try and see which works.

Comment: it was great it is working. but i have another issue that am having two different tables, after completing textboxes in one table it is not navigating to next table's textboxes, can i get some solution for this

Comment: @user3165411 This is not a helpdesk site. Please read the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help). If you've encountered another issue and it's not already answered, then post another question.